# My videocard 2080 super shows no signal

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi

I just built a new pc but the GPU is giving no signal to the monitor.

The specs are:

- Asus TUF B450 PLUS GAMING
- Ryzen 5 3600X
- Crucial ballistix gaming memory - 16GB (2x8) DDR4-3200
- MSI geforce 2080 super (gaming trio)
- Mars gaming MPB650

When I switch it on the fans work and the lights are on, but I can't see anything in the monitor. I'm using the HDMI (I cannot use the DisplayPorts by now). Other comments:

- the HDMI is connected to the video card
- I tried with an only RAM stick.
- tried with and without the GPU (obviously, nothing happened)
- CMOS cleared and MoBo battery removed for 5 minutes.
- the MoBo is compatible out of the box with the CPU (it's written in the box)

I'd really appreciate it if you guys could help me. Thank you!! :)

Comment: Hi Daniel
did you check if your bios is up to date to be able to handle the cpu? if i remember correctly B450 motherboards need a BIOS update to be able to use zen 2 CPUs

Comment: Hi @TamalesRancheros, thanks for your comment. It should be compatible out of the box, the motherboard's box says so!

Comment: I know it says its Zen 2 ready, but if it doesn't even boot without a graphic card, then the issue is a Bios update. If you don't have at least a previous generation CPU to update your motherboard you could use the [Short Term Processor Loan Boot Kit](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/pa-100) from AMD

Comment: Uhmmm, yes, in that case, that might be the problem. I just surrendered and got my pc to a local computer shop. I hope they have an older CPU to update the bios. I'll update the post with the news. Muchas gracias amigo!